# Chef - Using template erb with array

Tags: ruby, templates, chef-infra, erb

Just having issues trying to get this to work. Not exactly sure where I went but I'm guessing it might have something to do with the undeclared "group".

So here is my code:

Attribute File:

```
default['dynamic']['config']['queueGroup'] = [
    {
        'groupName' => 'group1',
        'queueNameRegex' => 'temp.x',
        'showIndividualStats' => 'false',
    },
    {
        'groupName' => 'group2',
        'queueNameRegex' => 'temp.y',
        'showIndividualStats' => 'false',
    },
]
```

ERB Template:

```
queueGroups:
 <% @node['dynamic']['config']['queueGroup'].each do |group| %>
  <%= "" %>
  <% @group.each do |key, value| %>
    <%if key == "groupName" %>
     - groupName:<%= value %>
    <% else %>
      <%= "#{key}=#{value}" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Recipe:

```
template '/tmp/temp.config' do
  source 'config.yml.erb'
  owner 'test'
  group 'test'
  mode '0644'
  variables(
    rmq_host: node['fqdn'],
    rmq_port: node['dynamic']['config']['rmq_port'],
    rmq_usessl: node['dynamic']['config']['rmq_usessl'],
    rmq_username: node['dynamic']['config']['rmq_username'],
    rmq_password: node['dynamic']['config']['rmq_password'],
    rmq_display_name: node['fqdn'],
    rmq_socket_timeout: node['dynamic']['config']['rmq_socket_timeout'],
    rmq_connect_timeout: node['dynamic']['config']['rmq_connect_timeout'],
    rmq_metric_prefix: node['dynamic']['config']['rmq_metric_prefix']
  )
  action :create
end
```

Getting the following error when I try to run the recipe to create the template:

```
Running handlers:
[2020-10-15T23:02:31+11:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2020-10-15T23:02:31+11:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Infra Client failed. 5 resources updated in 07 seconds
[2020-10-15T23:02:31+11:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/cookbooks/london/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2020-10-15T23:02:31+11:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2020-10-15T23:02:31+11:00] FATAL: Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

Below is the Stacktrace output

```
Generated at 2020-10-15 23:02:31 +1100
Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError:

Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass) on line #30:

 28:  <<% @node['dynamic']['config']['queueGroup'].each do |group| %>
 29:   <%= "" %>
 30:   <% @group.each do |key, value| %>
 31:     <%if key == "groupName" %>
 32:      - groupName:<%= value %>

  /tmp/cookbooks/default/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/test/templates/default/temp.config.erb:30:in `block (2 levels) in evaluate'
  /tmp/cookbooks/default/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/test/templates/default/temp.config.erb:28:in `each'
  /tmp/cookbooks/default/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/test/templates/default/temp.config.erb:28:in `block in evaluate'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/erubis-2.7.0/lib/erubis/evaluator.rb:74:in `instance_eval'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/erubis-2.7.0/lib/erubis/evaluator.rb:74:in `evaluate'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/mixin/template.rb:161:in `_render_template'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/mixin/template.rb:146:in `render_template'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/provider/template/content.rb:76:in `file_for_provider'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/file_content_management/content_base.rb:42:in `tempfile'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:455:in `tempfile'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:329:in `do_generate_content'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:141:in `action_create'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/provider.rb:189:in `run_action'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/resource.rb:586:in `run_action'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/runner.rb:74:in `run_action'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/runner.rb:108:in `block in run_all_actions'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/runner.rb:108:in `each'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/runner.rb:108:in `run_all_actions'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/runner.rb:132:in `block in converge'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:96:in `block in execute_each_resource'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:115:in `call_iterator_block'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:86:in `step'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:94:in `execute_each_resource'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.6.0/forwardable.rb:230:in `execute_each_resource'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/runner.rb:130:in `converge'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/client.rb:703:in `block in converge'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/client.rb:698:in `catch'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/client.rb:698:in `converge'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/client.rb:722:in `converge_and_save'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/client.rb:288:in `run'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/application.rb:320:in `run_with_graceful_exit_option'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/application.rb:296:in `block in run_chef_client'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:42:in `with_server_connectivity'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/application.rb:279:in `run_chef_client'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/application/base.rb:330:in `run_application'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/application.rb:69:in `run'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-bin-15.8.23/bin/chef-client:25:in `<top (required)>'
  /bin/chef-client:177:in `load'
  /bin/chef-client:177:in `<main>'


/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/mixin/template.rb:163:in `rescue in _render_template'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/mixin/template.rb:158:in `_render_template'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/mixin/template.rb:146:in `render_template'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/provider/template/content.rb:76:in `file_for_provider'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/file_content_management/content_base.rb:42:in `tempfile'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:455:in `tempfile'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:329:in `do_generate_content'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:141:in `action_create'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/provider.rb:189:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/resource.rb:586:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/runner.rb:74:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/runner.rb:108:in `block in run_all_actions'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/runner.rb:108:in `each'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/runner.rb:108:in `run_all_actions'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/runner.rb:132:in `block in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:96:in `block in execute_each_resource'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:115:in `call_iterator_block'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:86:in `step'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:94:in `execute_each_resource'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.6.0/forwardable.rb:230:in `execute_each_resource'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/runner.rb:130:in `converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/client.rb:703:in `block in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/client.rb:698:in `catch'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/client.rb:698:in `converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/client.rb:722:in `converge_and_save'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/client.rb:288:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/application.rb:320:in `run_with_graceful_exit_option'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/application.rb:296:in `block in run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:42:in `with_server_connectivity'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/application.rb:279:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/application/base.rb:330:in `run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/application.rb:69:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-bin-15.8.23/bin/chef-client:25:in `<top (required)>'
/bin/chef-client:177:in `load'
/bin/chef-client:177:in `<main>'

>>>> Caused by NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
/tmp/cookbooks/default/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/test/templates/default/temp.config.erb:30:in `block (2 levels) in evaluate'
/tmp/cookbooks/default/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/test/templates/default/temp.config.erb:28:in `each'
/tmp/cookbooks/default/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/test/templates/default/temp.config.erb:28:in `block in evaluate'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/erubis-2.7.0/lib/erubis/evaluator.rb:74:in `instance_eval'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/erubis-2.7.0/lib/erubis/evaluator.rb:74:in `evaluate'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/mixin/template.rb:161:in `_render_template'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/mixin/template.rb:146:in `render_template'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/provider/template/content.rb:76:in `file_for_provider'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/file_content_management/content_base.rb:42:in `tempfile'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:455:in `tempfile'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:329:in `do_generate_content'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:141:in `action_create'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/provider.rb:189:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/resource.rb:586:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/runner.rb:74:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/runner.rb:108:in `block in run_all_actions'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/runner.rb:108:in `each'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/runner.rb:108:in `run_all_actions'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/runner.rb:132:in `block in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:96:in `block in execute_each_resource'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:115:in `call_iterator_block'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:86:in `step'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:94:in `execute_each_resource'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.6.0/forwardable.rb:230:in `execute_each_resource'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/runner.rb:130:in `converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/client.rb:703:in `block in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/client.rb:698:in `catch'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/client.rb:698:in `converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/client.rb:722:in `converge_and_save'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/client.rb:288:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/application.rb:320:in `run_with_graceful_exit_option'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/application.rb:296:in `block in run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:42:in `with_server_connectivity'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/application.rb:279:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/application/base.rb:330:in `run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.8.23/lib/chef/application.rb:69:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-bin-15.8.23/bin/chef-client:25:in `<top (required)>'
/bin/chef-client:177:in `load'
/bin/chef-client:177:in `<main>'
```

Hope someone could quickly help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: **Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report** Please edit your question and add the content of the stacktrace there. Without this, we can't help you either as we don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Sure thing, have updated the post and provided the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

In your template, you are referring to `@group` (which is an instance variable) rather than `group` (the local variable set by the `each` method. SInce this instance variable is not defined, it is assumed to be `nil` when you call `each` on it in line 30.

In templates, you usually only refer to data passed in with the `variables` attribute as instance variables. In your example, you could e.g. refer to `@ rmq_host` since you explicitly pass it in.

Other variables, especially block parameters for loops are referred to without a leading `@` character since they are only local variables.

To fix your template, make sure to refer to the correct variables:

```
queueGroups:
 <% node['dynamic']['config']['queueGroup'].each do |group| %>
  <%= "" %>
  <% group.each do |key, value| %>
    <%if key == "groupName" %>
     - groupName:<%= value %>
    <% else %>
      <%= "#{key}=#{value}" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I am still getting the same problem. I have noticed that this works perfectly fine from a single cookbook but if I call something like `chef-client -z -n <run_list name>` i experience the above error vs `chef-client -zr recipe[cookbook::recipe]`

Answer (score 0):

There is a small error in reading the variables inside the template. When you need to reference `node` attributes or template variables `@` is not required. Due to the prefix the attributes and variables are getting a `nil` value.

Only the variables passed from within `variables()` of a `template` resource need to be prefixed with `@`.

So then with these modifications, we will have a template `temp.config.j2` like below:

```
queueGroups:
 <% node['dynamic']['config']['queueGroup'].each do |group| %>
  <%= "" %>
  <% group.each do |key, value| %>
    <%if key == "groupName" %>
     - groupName:<%= value %>
    <% else %>
      <%= "#{key}=#{value}" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Note that `@` is not used before the node attribute, and `group` in `group.each`.

Or you could pass the `['dynamic']['config']['queueGroup']` as a variable in template.

```rb
template '/tmp/temp.config' do
  # rest of the declarations
  variables(
    dynamic_config_queuegroup: node['dynamic']['config']['queueGroup']
    # other variables
  )
```

Then use it in template like:

```
queueGroups:
 <% @dynamic_config_queuegroup.each do |group| %>
  <%= "" %>
  <% group.each do |key, value| %>
```